# Guardar un archivo en la base de datos sin crear directorio virtual

Tags: java, archivo, servlets, google-app-engine

buen dia,

Estoy teniendo un problema, estoy haciendo un proyecto en Java y lo subo a app engine, pero app engine tiene un problema y es que no permite crear directorios virtuales, entonces lo que quiero hacer para solucionar este problema, es guardar mis archivos en DataStore y poderlos descargar sin necesidad de que esten en un directorio virtual, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("Error: El formulario debe contener enctype=multipart/form-data");
            writer.flush();
            return;
         }
         DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
         factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
         factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
         ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
         upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
         upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
         String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("./") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
         File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
         if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
             uploadDir.mkdir();
         }
         try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {

            for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    item.write(storeFile);
                    Cuenta cuenta=new Cuenta();

                    //Covertir archivo en Base64
                    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    byte[] fileArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                    InputStream inputStream;
                    Text encodedFile = new Text("");
                    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream.read(fileArray);
        encodedFile =new Text(base64.encodeToString(fileArray));
                    cuenta.setCertificado(encodedFile);
                    cuenta.setId(Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("cuenta").toString()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                           request.setAttribute("message","Ocurrio un error codificando el archivo.");
                           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Cuentas");
                           rd.forward(request, response);
                    }

                    Result respuesta=cuenta.Salvar(datastore, "");
                    request.setAttribute("message","Archivo cargado con exito");
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Cuentas");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message","Ocurrio un error cargando el archivo");
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Cuentas");
           rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Que hago? En mi formulario cargo el archivo, y vengo al servlet y tomo el archivo, lo guardo en un directorio virtual y lo conviento a base64, pero como puedo recibir el archivo, y de una pasarlo a base 64 sin crear el directorio virtual, se puese? Quedo atento a cualquier duda, gracias.

Comment: Pues vas bien ya lo tienes como String 64 bits solo deberias de guardar ese String en base de datos o te da algun error ?

Comment: No, esque ese string en base64 es de mi directorio virtual. no deseo crear un directorio virtual. quiero tener mi archivo en base64 sin tener que crear directorio virtual @RaulCacacho

Comment: Ya te entendi mejor dejame ver como te puedo ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilzar este ejemplo para poder crear tu `String64` no creando la ruta virtua, tiene los mismos parametros, espero te sirva

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Base64Servlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String imageBase64 = req.getParameter("base64");
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    writeOutputStream(imageBase64, out);

    resp.setContentType("image/png");
    resp.setHeader("Pragma", "");
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; fileName=image.png");
}

private void writeOutputStream(String value, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(value);
    BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
    ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", outputStream);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tu situación lo ideal seria usar [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage), que es un servicio de archivos distribuidos pensado para trabajar con los productos de Google Cloud.